# Ember Data 2 - Submit Two Associated Models in One Form

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Total Ember newb here. My back-end is written with Rails. That piece is fine, so assume all is well on the server side. Here are the specifics:

**I have two models** 
Project (Has Many Project Details)
Project Details (Belongs To Project)

**I have confirmed that:**

1. I am able to create a new Project from my projects/new.hbs template
2. My Index route retrieves all Projects and the Project Details associated with them.
3. My Show route retrieves an individual Project and the Project Details associated with them.

What I would like to do is, submit a project model along with a project detail model from my projects/new.hbs template.

I understand that the form in new.hbs should be in a component but I am keeping it simple for now. Once, I am able to create my associated models I will work on doing the same as a form component.

**Project Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
 project_details: DS.hasMany('project_detail', { async: true }),

 project_name: DS.attr('string'),
 status: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**Project Detail Model**

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
 project: DS.belongsTo('project', { async: true }),

 project_id: DS.attr('number'),
 feature_name: DS.attr('string'),
 hours_billed: DS.attr('number'),
 available_hours: DS.attr('number'),
 amout: DS.attr('number')
});
```

**Projects/New.js Route**

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({
      projects: this.store.createRecord('project'),
      project_details: this.store.createRecord('project_detail')
    });
  },
 actions: {
  create: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.controller.get('model').save().then(
    function() {
      self.transitionTo('projects.index');
    });
  }
 }
});
```

**Projects/New.hbs**

```
<form {{ action "create" on="submit" }}>
  <label for="project_name">Project Name</label>
  {{ input value=project_name }}
  <label for="status">Status</label>
  {{ input value=status }}
  <label for="feature_name">Feature Name</label>
  {{ input value=feature_name }}
  <label for="available_hours">Available Hours</label>
  {{ input value=available_hours }}
  <label for="hours_billed">Hours Billed</label>
  {{ input value=hours_billed }}
  <label for="amount">Amount</label>
  {{ input value=amount }}
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

**Router.js**

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('home');
  this.route('dashboard');
  this.route('login');
  this.resource('projects', function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('show', {path: '/:id'});
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:id/edit'});
  });
});
```

When I submit the form, the action appears to be called, but all data that is submitted is `NULL`, so evidently, my inputs are not being recognized. I have searched for a couple days and have not seen a solution for submitting multiple models. My code is a result of expanding on a standard POST along with how I handled retrieving my associated models via the RSVP Hash. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got some things that are not wired up correctly.

When you return the following from your route:

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    projects: this.store.createRecord('project'),
    project_details: this.store.createRecord('project_detail')
  });
},
```

In your template, you can use `{{model.something}}` to access that information, in your case you have access to `{{model.projects}}` and `{{model.project_details}}`.

You probably want to do the following in your `route` to setup easier access to your models in the templates.

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  //this._super(controller, model) I'll explain why this is commented
  controller.set('project', model.projects);
  controller.set('project_details', model.project_details); 
}
```

If you do this, then in your template you can do things like this:

```
<label>Project Name</label>
{{input value=project.project_name}}
{{project.project_name}}
```

Which brings to the next thing. When you have in your template the following:

```
{{ input value=project_name }}
```

What you're doing is binding the `input` value to the `project_name` property of your controller. If you use the [Ember Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ember-inspector/bmdblncegkenkacieihfhpjfppoconhi?hl=en) (hint, if you're not using it, you should. It makes life so much easier) you can probably check that the controller has that property `project_name` with the value you typed.

Before Ember 2.0 there was this thing called the [Object Controller](https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller/) (which you don't use anymore) that allowed proxying the model to the controller. Which meant that you could on your route do this:

```
model() {
   return this.store.createRecord('project');
}
```

And in your template you effectively to this:

```
<label>Project Name</label>
{{project_name}}
```

Today **you have to do this** (Unless you install [ember-legacy-controllers](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-controllers) which I don't recommend):

```
<label>Project Name</label>
{{model.project_name}}
```

As you can see, you need to add the `model` before the `project_name`. This is because the `model` returned from the route is set as a property of the controller by default. That's something we can change, of course. You could also do the following in your route:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
  controller.set('model', model.projects);
  controller.set('myProjectDetails', model.project_details);
}
```

And in the template you could now do the following:

```
<form {{ action "create" on="submit" }}>
 <label for="project_name">Project Name</label>
 {{ input value=model.project_name }}
 <label for="status">Status</label>
 {{ input value=model.status }}
 <label for="feature_name">Feature Name</label>
 {{ input value=myProjectDetails.feature_name }}
 <label for="available_hours">Available Hours</label>
 {{ input value=myProjectDetails.available_hours }}
 <label for="hours_billed">Hours Billed</label>
 {{ input value=myProjectDetails.hours_billed }}
 <label for="amount">Amount</label>
 {{ input value=amount }}
 <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Which means that your save function now works because the "project" is now your model. If you used my example of `setupController` where I did this:

```
controller.set('project', model.projects);
```

Then you would have to change your `create` action to this:

```
actions: {
  create: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.controller.get('project').save().then(
    function() {
     self.transitionTo('projects.index');
    });
  }
}
```

Also, do notice that you have your models declared with

```
//Project
project_details: DS.hasMany('project_detail', { async: true }),
//Project Detail
project: DS.belongsTo('project', { async: true }),
```

But you're not setting the relations in the code you posted. If you want the models to be related, in your create action you would need something like this (or in any other place really). I'm assuming in the following snippet that my `setupController` example is in the route so that the `project` is in the controller as `project` and the `project_details` as `project_details`.

```
 create: function() {
 var self = this;
 var project = this.controller.get('project');
 var projectDetails = this.controller.get('project_details');
 project.get('project_details').pushObject(projectDetails);
 project_details.set('project', project);

 project.save().then(function() {
    self.transitionTo('projects.index');
 });
}
```

Assuming you're using Ember Data 2.0, there's also another problem with this. When you save the `project` it will only make a post request to save the project itself (it won't save the newly created `project_details` with it). At the moment `JSONAPI`(the standard Ember Data 2.0 by default uses) does not have a solution for updating multiple resources in one go ([see this github issue](https://github.com/json-api/json-api/issues/795)). This means that you would have to save the `project_details` first and only then then `project` (which probably doesn't make sense looking at your models as it seems the `project_details` only exists under a `project`.)

It's the current state of affairs, as far as I know. I'm also looking for a good solution for this problem (I've hacked together solutions like only allowing to create a project_detail after the project is created, or having an extra attribute in the project with is a string of the serialized project_detail json and then have the backend to the things it needs)

Comment: Awesome post. Thank you for such a concise answer. I figured out half of what you have written and was going to post an update, however, I believe your post has gotten me 100% there. I believe we can save the Project and Project Details together by using an EmbeddedRecordsMixin? http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html
I might have misunderstood their purpose but it seems to me, this Mixin will allow models with associations to be saved together.

Comment: Glad it helped! Yes EmbededRecordsMixin should be our go to, but apparently there's a [bug](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3720) when using it with JSONAPIAdapter (and apparently JSONAPI does not define the semantics for such an operation yet). But if you're using the RESTAdapter it should work.

Comment: I'm still on Rails 4 with Ember Data 2.0, so I was able to stick with the RESTAdapter and it does appear to be working. Again, thank you, for this great explanation. Your post really cleared up the areas of Ember I was foggy on. Specifically, the Routes actions.

Comment: I once had the same doubts (still have on a lot of ember stuff, lol) so I felt that I should try to help. Really glad that it helped. Best of luck with your ember app.